# PHP 'or' operator rule?

Tags: php

Firstly, I am a novice as my name suggests so forgive me if I don't phrase what I am asking correctly!

I am an owner of a website which has products dynamically inserted into the database each night.

From the datafeeds pulled in, we make rules to EXCLUDE certain products within the feeds.

I am trying to add variants to these rules, but whenever I try to add in the variants using the 'or' operator that I looked up, nothing works at all, and in fact, nothing pulls through to the database.

Currently this is what is live and works:

```
    if ($gender == "Female" AND $display_price != null AND $kids != "Children")
```

('Female' products pulled in, but ignore/delete anything marked as 'Female" and 'Children')

I want to add variants in so that we can include products that don't fit the above criteria because a different label is used and have tried these with no success:

```
    if ($gender == "Female" OR $gender == "Women") AND $display_price != null AND $kids != "Children" OR $kids == "Kids")
```

also tried:

```
    if ($gender == "Female" || $gender == "Women") && $display_price != null && $kids != "Children" || $kids == "Kids")
```

So basically I want to pull in any 'Female' or 'Women' clothing products but ignore anything which is  kid's clothes.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Sorry guys, I should clarify I am not the developer obviously, he is out-of-action at the moment working on another big project.

Apologies if I mis-titled the topic.

But I am competent enough to make small cut and paste changes like this, I think!

Comment: very odd sounding db structure

Comment: Look up `if` statements.  Your if condition needs to be wrapped in parenthesis: `if (conditions)`.  In your latter statements, I see `if (conditions)conditions)`.

Comment: The title asks about OR but in the question body you only seem to care about making it work. Clarify the question title or the body please. In any case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you forgot brackets:

```
if (($gender == "Female" || $gender == "Women") && $display_price != null && $kids != "Children" || $kids == "Kids")
```

Comment: u forgot to add kids in separate brackets, kids have an or option too

Comment: Hi Jesbus, I copied and pasted your first response and it worked, then I was trying out some other responses just to see how they affected things.

Comment: Sorry, went back to your solution, think you might have changed it, now the new line above does not work for me! Can you share your original solution please?

Comment: Ok, I changed it back again

Comment: This worked in the end for me, thanks very much for your help!   if (($gender == "Female" || $gender == "Women") && $display_price != null && $kids != "Children" && $kids != "Kids")

Answer (score 1):

```
if (($gender == "Female" OR $gender == "Women") AND $display_price != null AND $kids != "Children" OR $kids == "Kids")
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting an error in your above code, you are using

```
if ($gender == "Female" OR $gender == "Women") AND $display_price != null AND $kids !="Children" OR $kids == "Kids")
```

rather it should be

```
if ( (condition1 or condition2) and condition3 and condition4 and (condition5 or condition6) )
```

In your case

```
if ( ($gender == "Female" OR $gender == "Women") AND $display_price != null AND ($kids !="Children" OR $kids == "Kids") )
```

the two conditions having "or" needs to be in separate brackets, within the whole condition

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are missing several brackets.

Try:

```
if (($gender == "Female" || $gender == "Women") && $display_price != null && ($kids != "Children" || $kids == "Kids"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing an openening parenthesis in both statements:

if (($gender == "Female" OR $gender == "Women") AND $display_price != null AND $kids != "Children" OR $kids == "Kids")

Answer (score 0):

Here is what u can try

```
 if($gender == "female" || $gender=="male" AND $display_price!=NULL){

    if($kids != "Children"){
    // Here will be item for the male or femaile with not price=Null and kids not==children
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your new IF Condition is syntactically wrong as it doesn't contains opening bracket in IF condition.

Secondly try this condition,

```
if (($gender == "Female" || $gender == "Women")
 && $display_price != null
 && ($kids != "Children" && $kids != "Kids"))
{
 //Your Code.
}
```